# How do I print a dataframe in R will all decimal values

Tags: r, format

I have a dataframe whose values I want to inspect, but when I print the dataframe, only 2 or 3 decimals are printed. I inspected the dataframe directly and confirmed that there are more decimal places than what is being printed.

So far I have tried `print(df, digits=10)` and `options(digits=10)` but these don't seem to be changing the print output.

Some screenshots:

## Printed output with too few decimals

[image: Printed output with too few decimals.]

## Actual data with all decimal values

[image: Actual data with all decimal values.]

Answer (score 3):

I do not exactly know how you load your data. However, your screenshot looks like you are

looking at data in a tibble format.

```
x=1.1111
tibble(x) -> x
print(x)
A tibble: 1 x 1
      x
  <dbl>
1  1.11
```

if you convert it to a data.frame, you can print easily all digits:

```
as.data.frame(x) -> x
print(x)
       x
1 1.1111
```

**Update:**
you can easily print a tibble in the format you are looking for using `print.data.frame()`

```
x = 1.234567890123456
tibble(x) -> x
print.data.frame(x, digits = 10)
#           x
#1 1.23456789

print.data.frame(x, digits = 11)
#             x
#1 1.2345678901
```