# how to get decimal values of whole number in r

Tags: r, dataframe, rounding

I happen to have a data set like this,

```
    options(pillar.sigfig = 5) 
a <- c(1.012,1,0,2.987,4)
b <- c(4.897,5,98,8.001,2.456)
tibble(A=a,
       B=b) -> tibble1
```

and the output looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have the decimal points for the whole number shown, I tried the `signif` function, but it could not get the decimal values for the whole table, but I got for each column (I want it to be reflected in the whole table though :P).

Expected Output, FYR:

[image]

Comment: If you are ok turning tibble into dataframe. `data.frame(tibble1)` should give you what you want.

Comment: Yea Sure ,Let me try

Comment: See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793834/how-do-i-print-a-dataframe-in-r-will-all-decimal-values/52794070#52794070).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decimals are not a property of the object, they are a property of the `print` method used on the object. For better or worse the `tibble` and `pillar` packages are very restrictive about how decimals get printed.

If you need to use `tbl`/`tbl_df` for other features, but don't like the print method, use a different `print` method.

Either:

```
print.data.frame(tibble1)
```

Or use this approach, [which the maintainers of `pillar` actually recommend](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/04/pillar-1-2-2/):

```
print.tbl_df <- function(x, ...) {
  print.data.frame(x, ...)
  invisible(x)
}

tibble1
```